# No puedo usar pytorch 11.1 con GPU, usando una NVIDIA 730 GT, que debo hacer

Tags: python, python-3.x, librería, tensorflow, cuda

Use GPU-Z para obtener las especificaciones de mi GPU, y su controlador en este caso 461.62

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparentemente tendria que estar todo bien entre la version de mis drivers y la version de CUDA, no? (que esto este asi solo garantiza lo de los drivers, no que sea compatible con el hardware osea la placa de video)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego instale la GPU-accelerated library of primitives for DL, NVIDIA cuDNN en su version...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta version que es compatible (en teoria), para CUDA 11.0, 11.1 y 11.2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que se debe escoger el pytorch en funcion del CUDA que quieras instalar, pero en este caso se que usare el pytorch para la 11.1 osea que elegi esa version.

Y puse la carpeta en la direccion MiPC/C:/y ahi cuda  y tambien coloque las 3 variables de entorno.
Me guie con este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StH5YNrY0mE

Tambien instale el CUDA Toolkit 11.1.0, que creo en mi caso es el que es consistente con el resto pero estoy en dudas. Aun asi aqui dejo el link de donde lo baje con el exe[local].

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.1.0-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora instale el pytorch para la version 11.1 (que es la que queria) desde el gestor pip, simplemente poniendo el siguiente code copiado de la page:

pip install torch==1.8.1+cu111 torchvision==0.9.1+cu111 torchaudio===0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estube probando pytorch en consola con la impresion de un tensor, y aparentemente funciona perfecto, pero claro hasta ahora con eso solo pruebo que funcione torch con la CPU, ya que no especifique el device.

```
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.rand(5, 3)
>>> print(x)
tensor([[0.1242, 0.4253, 0.9530],
        [0.2290, 0.8633, 0.2871],
        [0.3668, 0.5047, 0.7253],
        [0.9148, 0.0506, 0.3024],
        [0.3645, 0.1265, 0.1900]])
```

Luego ejecute esto:

```
import torch
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

Y me devolvio True, a lo que entiendo que CUDA si funciona (pero no es asi).

Lo cual es extraño, aqui encontre una page, donde dicen "que esto funciona" pero en mi caso que devuelva un True parece que NO me garantiza que realmente funcione..., osea que devuelva True solo te indica que el pytorch cuda que pusiste este instalado (y supuestamente verificar si su controlador de GPU y CUDA están habilitados) pero no te indica realmente si esta funcionando o no, eso es lo que note (te daras cuenta si funciona o no al intentar usar pytorch con GPU).
Igual paso el link:
https://mundowin.com/como-instalar-pytorch-en-windows-paso-a-paso/

Estuve viendo gente a la que le ocurrio algo similar, pero no me funcionan las soluciones que plantean(o porque estan desactualizadas las soluciones, o quizas yo no se hacerlo bien). Ellos dicen que instale pytorch desde el codigo fuente o algo asi...

Aun asi creo que el problema es pytorch.
y el cuda cc, imagino que debe ser un compiler pero no lo se con seguridad, que dicen?

En el siguiente link, plantean una "guia de instalacion algo complicada para mi al menos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source

Fui a ese repositorio de github y descargue el proyecto a mi pc.

Intente ejecutar ese setup.py con torch anterior eliminado y sin torch anterior eliminado, y tira...

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\pytorch-master>python setup.py
Building wheel torch-1.9.0a0+gitUnknown
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Realmente no entiendo para que es eso...

Lo que me sigue dejando en duda es eso del compilador que pide en C++
Y respecto al CUDA Toolkit 11.1 y el NVIDIA cudDNN (en version 11.1) en teoria los podria dejar asi... como mostre que les instale mas arriba, no?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todos modos, al no poder usar con GPU, adapte mi proyecto a CPU modificando todo lo que diga to_gpu o to_device, y andubo con CPU usando los 3 en 11.1, pero como CPU (lento, muy lento, per andubo, osea que con eso ya descarto que sea mi proyecto)

Si lo ejecuto con GPU, usando el supuesto CUDA 11.1 instalado me tira estos errores, y ahi el problema:

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>python main.py
starting up on 127.0.0.1 port 65432
Using cache found in C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master
Loading weights:  None
Using cache found in C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\facebookresearch_WSL-Images_master
Using cache found in C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master
waiting for a connection
connection from ('127.0.0.1', 13676)
Connection closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    pose_data = pose_estimator.get_pose_data(img.copy())
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend\utils\pose_estimator.py", line 74, in get_pose_data
    heatmaps, pafs, scale, pad = self.infer_fast(img)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend\utils\pose_estimator.py", line 49, in infer_fast
    stages_output = self.net(tensor_img)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend\emotion_models\with_mobilenet.py", line 134, in forward
    backbone_features = self.model(x)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 119, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 119, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 399, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 395, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Trate de describir d ela mejor manera que pude todo lo que hice haber si ustedes encuentran el error :( , pero sigue sin funcionar...
Probe si la camara es correcta y opencv la detecta y da video streaming osea que un problema con la webcam esta descartado.

Aun asi sigue tirando esto...

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Ya no se mas que hacer para hacer funcionar a pytorch en mi pc, espero realmente puedan ayudarme. Como veran trate de explicarme lo mejor posible, pero encerio que no se mas que hacerle.

---

Si bien siempre trabaje con Python 3.8.5 (el que me vino con Anaconda) desde la propia Anaconda prompt, hice las instalaciones con el gesto pip, ahora lo probe con conda install

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\pytorch-master>pip uninstall torch
Found existing installation: torch 1.8.1+cu111
Uninstalling torch-1.8.1+cu111:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\caffe2\*
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch-1.8.1+cu111.dist-info\*
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\*
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\scripts\convert-caffe2-to-onnx.exe
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\scripts\convert-onnx-to-caffe2.exe
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled torch-1.8.1+cu111

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\pytorch-master>conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - cudatoolkit=11.1
    - pytorch
    - torchaudio
    - torchvision


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-4.10.0               |   py38haa244fe_0         3.1 MB  conda-forge
    cudatoolkit-11.1.1         |       heb2d755_7        1.20 GB  conda-forge
    libuv-1.41.0               |       h8ffe710_0         341 KB  conda-forge
    ninja-1.10.2               |       h5362a0b_0         273 KB  conda-forge
    python_abi-3.8             |           1_cp38           4 KB  conda-forge
    pytorch-1.8.1              |py3.8_cuda11.1_cudnn8_0        1.53 GB  pytorch
    torchaudio-0.8.1           |             py38         2.7 MB  pytorch
    torchvision-0.9.1          |       py38_cu111         7.5 MB  pytorch
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        2.74 GB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cudatoolkit        conda-forge/win-64::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-heb2d755_7
  libuv              conda-forge/win-64::libuv-1.41.0-h8ffe710_0
  ninja              conda-forge/win-64::ninja-1.10.2-h5362a0b_0
  python_abi         conda-forge/win-64::python_abi-3.8-1_cp38
  pytorch            pytorch/win-64::pytorch-1.8.1-py3.8_cuda11.1_cudnn8_0
  torchaudio         pytorch/win-64::torchaudio-0.8.1-py38
  torchvision        pytorch/win-64::torchvision-0.9.1-py38_cu111

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  conda               pkgs/main::conda-4.9.2-py38haa95532_0 --> conda-forge::conda-4.10.0-py38haa244fe_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
torchvision-0.9.1    | 7.5 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
conda-4.10.0         | 3.1 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
python_abi-3.8       | 4 KB      | ############################################################################ | 100%
libuv-1.41.0         | 341 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
pytorch-1.8.1        | 1.53 GB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
cudatoolkit-11.1.1   | 1.20 GB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
torchaudio-0.8.1     | 2.7 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
ninja-1.10.2         | 273 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: / "By downloading and using the CUDA Toolkit conda packages, you accept the terms and conditions of the CUDA End User License Agreement (EULA): https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html"

done
```

Veo que tambien actualizo el channel de paquetes aqui:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  conda               pkgs/main::conda-4.9.2-py38haa95532_0 --> conda-forge::conda-4.10.0-py38haa244fe_0
```

Desafortunadamente tampoco funciono repitiendo el mismo error de cuando lo instale con el gestor pip

Ahora vi que algunos usan un virtual enviroment para hacerle funcionar y que no tenga conflictos con otros paquetes

https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html

https://tenpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/conda.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518050/conda-install-and-update-do-not-work-also-solving-environment-get-errors

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBfM5l9VK5c

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC>python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
>>> exit()

(base) C:\Users\MIPC>cd "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP"

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP>python List_Available_Webcams.py
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
[0, 1, 3, 4]

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP>python Video_Camera_Basic_Script.py
[ WARN:1] global
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP>python Video_Camera_Basic_Script.py
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP>cd "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend"

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>python main.py
starting up on 127.0.0.1 port 65432
Using cache found in C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master
Loading weights:  None
Using cache found in C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\facebookresearch_WSL-Images_master
Using cache found in C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master
waiting for a connection
connection from ('127.0.0.1', 47773)
Connection closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    pose_data = pose_estimator.get_pose_data(img.copy())
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend\utils\pose_estimator.py", line 74, in get_pose_data
    heatmaps, pafs, scale, pad = self.infer_fast(img)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend\utils\pose_estimator.py", line 49, in infer_fast
    stages_output = self.net(tensor_img)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend\emotion_models\with_mobilenet.py", line 134, in forward
    backbone_features = self.model(x)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 119, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 119, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 399, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 395, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~Sourc
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>conda uninstall torch
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - torch



(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend> pip uninstall torch
Found existing installation: torch 1.8.1
Uninstalling torch-1.8.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\caffe2
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch-1.8.1-py3.8.egg-info
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\scripts\convert-caffe2-to-onnx-script.py
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\scripts\convert-caffe2-to-onnx.exe
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\scripts\convert-onnx-to-caffe2-script.py
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\scripts\convert-onnx-to-caffe2.exe
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled torch-1.8.1

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>conda --version
conda 4.10.0

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.3|     pyhd3eb1b0_0           9 KB
    backports.tempfile-1.0     |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          11 KB
    libuv-1.40.0               |       he774522_0         255 KB
    ninja-1.10.2               |   py38h6d14046_0         247 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         522 KB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  backports.functoo~                             1.6.1-py_0 --> 1.6.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  libuv                conda-forge::libuv-1.41.0-h8ffe710_0 --> pkgs/main::libuv-1.40.0-he774522_0
  ninja                conda-forge::ninja-1.10.2-h5362a0b_0 --> pkgs/main::ninja-1.10.2-py38h6d14046_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  backports.tempfile                               1.0-py_1 --> 1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
ninja-1.10.2         | 247 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
libuv-1.40.0         | 255 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
backports.functools_ | 9 KB      | ############################################################################ | 100%
backports.tempfile-1 | 11 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>conda config --add channels conda-forge

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>conda config --add channels conda-forge
Warning: 'conda-forge' already in 'channels' list, moving to the top

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>conda config --set channel_priority strict

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>conda install --channel=conda-forge physics-tenpy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining boto:   2%|█▍
```

Y EL CODE SIGUE CON ALGUNOS CONFLICTOS QUE DICE QUE ENCUENTRA CON TRAS EJECUTAR conda install --channel=conda-forge physics-tenpy
Esto tomo unas horas pero no soluciono nada.
Osea que al final me tire por intentar lo del venv, realmente no entiendo porque tendria que funcionar pero... solo me queda probar

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC>conda activate tenpy

(tenpy) C:\Users\MIPC>python
Python 3.9.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 21 2021, 04:59:43) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
>>> exit()

(tenpy) C:\Users\MIPC>conda install pytorch cudatoolkit -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\envs\tenpy

  added / updated specs:
    - cudatoolkit
    - pytorch


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    blas-2.108                 |              mkl          13 KB  conda-forge
    blas-devel-3.9.0           |            8_mkl          12 KB  conda-forge
    liblapacke-3.9.0           |            8_mkl         3.9 MB  conda-forge
    mkl-devel-2020.4           |     h57928b3_312         5.6 MB  conda-forge
    mkl-include-2020.4         |     hb70f87d_311         696 KB  conda-forge
    pytorch-1.8.1              |py3.9_cuda11.1_cudnn8_0        1.53 GB  pytorch
    typing_extensions-3.7.4.3  |             py_0          25 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        1.54 GB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  blas               conda-forge/win-64::blas-2.108-mkl
  blas-devel         conda-forge/win-64::blas-devel-3.9.0-8_mkl
  cudatoolkit        conda-forge/win-64::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-heb2d755_7
  liblapacke         conda-forge/win-64::liblapacke-3.9.0-8_mkl
  libuv              conda-forge/win-64::libuv-1.41.0-h8ffe710_0
  mkl-devel          conda-forge/win-64::mkl-devel-2020.4-h57928b3_312
  mkl-include        conda-forge/win-64::mkl-include-2020.4-hb70f87d_311
  ninja              conda-forge/win-64::ninja-1.10.2-h5362a0b_0
  pytorch            pytorch/win-64::pytorch-1.8.1-py3.9_cuda11.1_cudnn8_0
  typing_extensions  conda-forge/noarch::typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
typing_extensions-3. | 25 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
mkl-devel-2020.4     | 5.6 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
mkl-include-2020.4   | 696 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
blas-devel-3.9.0     | 12 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
pytorch-1.8.1        | 1.53 GB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
liblapacke-3.9.0     | 3.9 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
blas-2.108           | 13 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - "By downloading and using the CUDA Toolkit conda packages, you accept the terms and conditions of the CUDA End User License Agreement (EULA): https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html"

done
```

De todos modos tuve problemas al ejecutar el proyecto, instale algunas paqueterias necesarias, pero tira errores que sin un virtual enviroment no daba, como:

```
(tenpy) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend>python main.py
starting up on 127.0.0.1 port 65432
Using cache found in C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master
Loading weights:  None
Using cache found in C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\facebookresearch_WSL-Images_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    depth_estimator = DepthEstimator()
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\VtuberProject\Assets\TrackingBackend\utils\depth_estimator.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.midas = torch.hub.load("intel-isl/MiDaS", "MiDaS")
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\envs\tenpy\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 339, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\envs\tenpy\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 368, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master\hubconf.py", line 15, in MiDaS
    model = MidasNet()
  File "C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master\midas\midas_net.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.pretrained, self.scratch = _make_encoder(backbone="resnext101_wsl", features=features, use_pretrained=use_pretrained)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master\midas\blocks.py", line 7, in _make_encoder
    pretrained = _make_pretrained_resnext101_wsl(use_pretrained)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\intel-isl_MiDaS_master\midas\blocks.py", line 85, in _make_pretrained_resnext101_wsl
    resnet = torch.hub.load("facebookresearch/WSL-Images", "resnext101_32x8d_wsl")
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\envs\tenpy\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 339, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\anaconda3\envs\tenpy\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 368, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\facebookresearch_WSL-Images_master\hubconf.py", line 39, in resnext101_32x8d_wsl
    return _resnext('resnext101_32x8d', Bottleneck, [3, 4, 23, 3], True, progress, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MIPC/.cache\torch\hub\facebookresearch_WSL-Images_master\hubconf.py", line 23, in _resnext
    model = ResNet(block, layers, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'groups'
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Osea que supongo que tampoco es una solucion viable.

Lo que me queda pensar es lo del tema que quizas CUDA Toolkit, cuDNN o/y pyTorch con GPU, no son complatibles con mi Nvidia 730 GT

Cheque aqui y como se ve en la imagen encontre mi placa de video en uno de los apartados, aunque no entiendo bien que significa (?)

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no entiendo es como segun el Compute Capability asociado a la placa puedo saber si es o no compatible y cual version debo descargar, quizas estube probando todo este tiempo con la 11.1 pero enrealidad necesito otra o no se la verdad...

Como hay 2 de las 730 GT mando foto de la caja de la mia, no se cual es realmente, aunque dice 2GB RAM DDR3:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que version deberia usar? Hay alguna compatible?
Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Pasé por algo similar, a revisar detalladamente las versiones compatibles del software que estás usando junto con CUDA. Saludos y éxitos con la aventura :D

Comment: Es complicado darte alguna guía ya que windows no es precisamente una plataforma sencilla para ponerse a compilar módulos de python. Lo que te aconsejo es que, ya que parece que usas la distribución anaconda, uses conda para instalar pytorch.

Comment: Osea que sugieren  que en vez de instalarlo con pip, haga pip uninstall pytorch, y lo instale ahora por conda?
Lo unico que no entiendo es a que se tefieren en la pagina oficial de pytorch al armarte el comando de instalacion por conda, cuando dicen **NOTE: 'conda-forge' channel is required for cudatoolkit 11.1**

Comment: Los _canales_ de conda son repositorios desde donde descarga los paquetes. El canal `conda-forge` es un canal oficial con paquetes más actualizados que los que vienen por defecto en la distribución anaconda.

Comment: He probado con una _GeForce GT 740_ y me dice pytorch que es muy vieja y que ya no está soportada. Me temo que a tu tarjeta gráfica le pasará lo mismo.

Comment: Disculpa ChemaCortes, como sabes que una placa es o no compatible, yo vi algunas cosas pero de los drivers. Recuerdas como verificaste eso de la compatibilidad del modelo de la placa de video ?

Comment: Yo estube viendo como puse en la actualizacion por edicion de la pregunta, que aparece en uno de los apartados de este link https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute 2 placas 730 GT (Aunque no se cual se corresponde con la mia, asociadas en una tabla con una Compute Capability, eso que significa? Y como podria saber se es compatible y que version usar apartir de ello?

Comment: No sé qué significa que haya dos entradas para tu placa. En mi caso, fue al activar dispositivo cuda con pytorch cuando me dijo que no tenía suficiente capacidad de cómputo y que mi tarjeta no estaba soportada (requiere `compute capability > 3.5`, mayor que lo que dice la documentación).

Comment: Estube viendo y aparentemente con la 8.0 anda mi GPU Nvidia, el tema es que no se que paquetes debo instalar de esta pagina para ello?

https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Answer (score 3):

Debido a que mi placa de video es la versión de la 730 GT pero de 128 bit y no la de 64 bit, entonces tengo menos cuda cores. Y la versión que me seria compatible seria la CUDA 8.0

De hecho en este [foro de nvidia](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/install-cuda-nvidia-driver-and-cudnn-for-geforce-gt-730/59770) un usuario moderador de nvidia sugiere:

> Do a proper install of CUDA 8 and run deviceQuery on it.

Entonces tendré que quitar el otro CUDA Toolkit anterior, y cambiar su respectivo cuDNN por los de la versión 8.0

- CUDA Toolkit 8.0 - Feb 2017 https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive
- cuDNN, viejo desde https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive#a-collapse713-8

Para un Pytorch viejo tendrás que usar un python viejo, osea que tendrás que buscar una versión de Anaconda que sea con la versión de python que necesitas.

Desde [aquí](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) instalo los Anaconda viejos

Ahora tendrás que actualizar el gestor de paquetes de python `pip`

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/ef/60d7ba03b5c442309ef42e7d69959f73aacccd0d86008362a681c4698e83/pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
```

Ahora tendré que instalar un pytorch que sea apto para esa versión de CUDA Toolkit

- https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

## Opcion 1 (con conda) :

```
conda install pytorch=0.4.1 cuda80 -c pytorch
```

Pero me a mi me falla.

También puedes intentar esto...

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>conda config --add channels conda-forge
Warning: 'conda-forge' already in 'channels' list, moving to the top
```

Pero en mi caso ya estaba el channel como prioritario, y no hace realmente diferencia.

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>conda install pytorch -c pytorch
Solving environment: failed

InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec: =2.7

Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001

Current thread 0x00002614 (most recent call first):
```

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491650/torch-1-1-0-cp37-cp37m-win-amd64-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform) también hay una solución sobre ese error, que puedes probar:

Si `conda` te instala una versión de pytorch inferior a la deseada ver [este link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-installs-version-1-7-1-instead-of-1-8-0/115138), ya que puede que necesites actualizar `conda`. Lo mismo ocurriría pero a la inversa si es que estas buscando versiones anteriores asociada a versiones de `conda` mas viejas (pero esto no esta asegurado que funcione correctamente)

## Opcion 2 (con `pip install nombre_del_paquete`)

```
pip install pytorch
pip install torchvision
pip install torchaudio
```

El problema con esto es que torch no se instalara con pip así nomas.
Y que torchvision y torchaudio se instalaran en la versión que tenga `pip` (simplemente con poner su nombre porque el gestor ya los tiene y no los esta bajando de ningún lado), pero probablemente eso no te convenga porque sera difícil que sea compatible con el pytorch que quieras instalar tu (mas si es uno viejo como en este caso, esto depende mas de la versión de pip las versiones que tenga de cada paquetería).

## Opcion 3 (con `pip install archivo.whl`):

```
for CUDA 8.0
Download and install wheel from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch_stable.html
```

A mi ninguna de las 2 me funciono realmente, ósea que lo hare con `pip install` "y el whell"

para este caso descargare los `.whl` desde este [link](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch_stable.html)

Debes tener en cuenta cual es tu S.O., siendo amd64 para Windows 64bits y el cp que sea de la versión de python en donde vas a instalar el torch.

Aquí lo explican mejor:

- [what does version name cp27 or cp35 mean in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023557/what-does-version-name-cp27-or-cp35-mean-in-python)

También con este comando compruebas que tu SO sea de 64 bits, en este caso devolvió 64 porque si es un Windows x64 (también conocido como x86_64 y AMD64)

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
64
```

Por ejemplo este si es de 64 bits pero no es la versión 3.6 de python, sino la 3.9, por eso da este error.

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchaudio-0.8.1-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: torchaudio-0.8.1-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Al final puede instalarlo así, recuerda que al poner torch te indicara en caso de ya tener un torchvision o/y torchaudio si estos 2 son compatibles con esta versión de torch

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip install torch-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: torch-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip install torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\mipc\desktop\mati\vtuber_hp\torch-for-cuda-8\torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: torch
  Attempting uninstall: torch
    Found existing installation: torch 1.8.1
    Uninstalling torch-1.8.1:
      Successfully uninstalled torch-1.8.1
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchvision 0.9.1 requires torch==1.8.1, but you have torch 1.0.0 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 0.8.1 requires torch==1.8.1, but you have torch 1.0.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed torch-1.0.0

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> exit()

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip install torch-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\mipc\desktop\mati\vtuber_hp\torch-for-cuda-8\torch-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: torch
  Attempting uninstall: torch
    Found existing installation: torch 1.0.0
    Uninstalling torch-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled torch-1.0.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchvision 0.9.1 requires torch==1.8.1, but you have torch 1.0.1 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 0.8.1 requires torch==1.8.1, but you have torch 1.0.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed torch-1.0.1

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip uninstall torchvision
Found existing installation: torchvision 0.9.1
Uninstalling torchvision-0.9.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision-0.9.1.dist-info\*
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled torchvision-0.9.1

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip uninstall torchaudio
Found existing installation: torchaudio 0.8.1
Uninstalling torchaudio-0.8.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchaudio-0.8.1.dist-info\*
    c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled torchaudio-0.8.1

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip install torchaudio-0.8.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\mipc\desktop\mati\vtuber_hp\torch-for-cuda-8\torchaudio-0.8.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting torch==1.8.1
  Using cached torch-1.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (190.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch==1.8.1->torchaudio==0.8.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch==1.8.1->torchaudio==0.8.1) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch==1.8.1->torchaudio==0.8.1) (1.14.3)
Installing collected packages: torch, torchaudio
  Attempting uninstall: torch
    Found existing installation: torch 1.0.1
    Uninstalling torch-1.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled torch-1.0.1
Successfully installed torch-1.8.1 torchaudio-0.8.1

(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip install torchvision-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\mipc\desktop\mati\vtuber_hp\torch-for-cuda-8\torchvision-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision==0.2.0) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision==0.2.0) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision==0.2.0) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.1.1 in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision==0.2.0) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch->torchvision==0.2.0) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\mipc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch->torchvision==0.2.0) (3.7.4.3)
Installing collected packages: torchvision
Successfully installed torchvision-0.2.0
```

Siendo estos los `.whl` que me funcionaron

- `pip install torch-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
- `pip install torchaudio-0.8.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl`
- `pip install torchvision-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Por cierto, si en lugar de descargarlo y hacer este `pip install` en la carpeta donde están esos archivos descargados `.whl` ponía los links copiándoles directamente de la pagina también funciona del mismo modo.

Ahora al realizar esta comprobación debería salir algo así:

```py
In [1]: import torch

In [2]: torch.cuda.current_device()
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: torch.cuda.device(0)
Out[3]: <torch.cuda.device at 0x7efce0b03be0>

In [4]: torch.cuda.device_count()
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
Out[5]: 'GeForce GTX 950M'

In [6]: torch.cuda.is_available()
Out[6]: True
```

Pero ahora que estoy con un Anaconda viejo, y con un pytorch viejo (en este caso la 8.0) como decía la pagina del principio donde el moderador del foro de nvidia decía que para la 730 gt de 128bit soportaría CUDA Toolkit 8.0, me sale lo siguiente, incluso probando con varios cuDNN distintos todos de la 8.0

```py
import torch
>>> torch.cuda.current_device()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda__init.py", line 388, in current_device
    _lazy_init()
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda__init.py", line 164, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
>>> torch.cuda.device_count()
0
>>> torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda__init.py", line 276, in get_device_name
    return get_device_properties(device).name
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda__init.py", line 306, in get_device_properties
    _lazy_init()  # will define _get_device_properties
  File "C:\Users\MIPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda__init__.py", line 164, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

Ahora con esto ya ni detecta la placa de video...

Pero supongo que es un tema de CUDA, también intente probar ahora con el CUDA 11.1 y su respectivo cuDNN pero mientras use esta versión de Anaconda, de Python 3.6 o/y de pytorch no me detecta CUDA, tanto si uso el CUDA 8.0 o si uso versiones mas actuales que antes si andaban como la mencionada 11.1

Si alguien se le ocurre algo mas, o si tiene experiencia instalando pytorch u otros paquetes similares en GPU relativamente viejas, me ayudaría mucho que me den una ayuda o alguna idea. Si encuentro una solución, la pondré aquí para que quede y quizás le sirva a otro.